# Entity framework creating a non existent column in the query

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, ef-code-first

This has been puzzling me for quite some time but I keep getting an invalid identifier error when my entity framework tries to execute an oracle query. The classes in question are the following:

```
public class Projectship : ModelTrackingBase
{

    [Column("PROJECTID")]     
    public long ProjectId { get; set; }

    [Column("VISITID")]
    public long VisitId { get; set; } 

    public virtual Bpid Bpid { get; set; } //new
    public virtual Visit Visit { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
 public class Bpid : EntityIdBase
{
    [Column("BUDPRJID")]
    [MaxLength(38)]
    public string BPId { get; set; }

    [Column("DESCRIPTION")]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Column("CSTOBJ")]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Custobj { get; set; }

    [Column("PVID")]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Pvid { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Projectship> Projectships { get; set; }  

    public IEnumerable<Visit> Visits
    {
        get { return Projectships.Select(p => p.Visit); }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0}: {1}", BPId , Description); }
    }

}
```

Now the EntityIdBase has the following:

```
public class EntityIdBase : EntityBase
    {
        [Column("ID")]
        public long Id { get; set; }
    }
```

It tries to keep on looking for a column Bpid_Id in the query. Does someone have any idea?

Comment: What is the error message and when does it occur?

Comment: @Colin It gives the error /Extent1/./Bpid_Id/ Invalid identifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bpid_id is created by EF because it can't automatically determine the relationship. Try adding the annotation:

```
[ForeignKey("ID")]
public virtual Bpid Bpid { get; set; } //new
```

Answer (score 3):

You have specified a navigation property in the `Projectship` class

`public virtual Bpid Bpid { get; set; }`

You have not specified a foreign key to go with the navigation property so Entity Framework has chosen one, and it has chosen the name `Bpid_Id`. And it should be in the database. It should not be "non-existent".

You will probably find it easier to use Entity Framework if you add a foreign key like this:

`public int BpidId { get; set; }`

References:

[Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx)

[Making Do with Absent Foreign Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708747.aspx)

Comment: You pointed me into the correct direction! I feel dumb now that I have solved this :(